# looking for a workaround for a bug in google maps Projection

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working with google maps api 10 for some time now and there is a bug that i just cant fix because im 99.9% sure its within googles library.

I do a lot of Projection `.toPixels()` to draw stuff and all works fine. I zoom with custom zoom methods `mapController.setZoom(getZoom() +1)` and it all works UNTIL i use a pinch-zoom (2-finger zoom). After that, the Projection seems to be stuck within certain zoom levels.

If i pinch zoom from 12 to 11 the maps `getZoomLevel()` gives me 11 (it always reports the right level). Now if i use my zoomOut method i am on level 13 and the projection calculates all right for level 13 but every subsequent zoomOut only changes the maps zoom-level (internally, remember, device has no internet so no map data). The projection continues to calculate everything as if it was still zoomlevel 13!
Should i zoomIn the projection suddenly jumps to level 11, no matter what the real level of the map is. So if i pinch zoomed to 12 the projection is stuck at 11 / 13 and will only jump between those two if i zoom out/in.
IF i pinch-zoom again, the projection is updated but stuck again at the new level to which i pinch-zoomed.
So a pinch zoom without internet completely kills the projection and the whole map becomes useless (in my case i dont really need the visual map, i just need its geoPoint translation, thats the most important part).

Does anyone know a hotfix/workaround or anything that could help me other than to disable more than 1 pointer in the on-touch ?

Map Stuff in the constructor of my customMapView

```
    setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mapController = getController();

    mapController.setZoom(17);

    setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    getZoomButtonsController().setVisible(false);

    setSatellite(false);
    setTraffic(false);
    setClickable(true);
    preLoad();
```

and thats how i zoom with custom buttons

```
mapController.setZoom(getZoomLevel() + 1); // zoom in
mapController.setZoom(getZoomLevel() - 1); // zoom out
```

1) zoom buttons work
2) pinch zoom out
3) now the buttons/zoom via button shows the behaviour as described above


Additional Info:
i just used the apps "myTracks" and "Torque".
Both use googlemaps.
In both i have recorded tracks.
Now if i disable internet and use 2-finger zoom and after that zoom in/out with the usual buttons, at some point the track wanders off into some direction even if it is perfectly centered. Up to the point where the track is gone after lots of zoom out/in.
The second i reactivate internet and the map is able to load some tiles the NEXT zoom is working and all is fine... because the map seems to require some data from the internet to calculate something within the projection and this something seems to be provided by a 2-finger zoom... thats how i see it. 

3 Apps, all the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Your question it's quite confusing and you should re-word it.

But at least I understood that you are using the `MapView` in a device not connect to internet and that you have a problem synchronizing your projections with map zoom level.

First and most important, the problem is not in google maps and you will need to look for an issue in your code.

The most common error achieving the synchronization between `getZoomLevel()` and `Projection` is that it's often forgotten that the first is an integer value (it increases/decreases in discrete steps multiples of 1), while the map image and Projection can take values in between them to provide user with a smoother zoom in/out.

For example, when you pinch to zoom, while you keep your fingers in the screen and change the map size (and projections) the method `getZoomLevel()` always returns the zoom level that map has when you started the pinch-to-zoom. Only after you stop the pinch to zoom (taking the finger off from screen) the method `getZoomLevel()` will return the final select zoom level. But if don't finishs here, because an animation continues the map image zoom in/out to the closest integer zoom level (the one started being returned by `getZoomLevel()` after you stop the pinch to zoom).

Hope you understood it. If not post an example of your code exemplifying the problem and you will get help to correct it.

Regards.

Comment: im sorry, i did describe the problem as clear as i can :/ but it has nothing to do with what ur describing. Im working with the map for almost 2 years now, its not that simple, the issue is buried somewhere deep inside the library

Comment: Í'm also working with google map for almost 2 years :-) Before post my answer, I've tested one of my programs displaying a path with 10.000 points in a device disconnected from network. It never failed to correctly handle the zoom. I've tried several pich to zoom (in and out) followed by zoom buttons (and also an auto-zoom developed by me) and all of them worked fine. Read carefully what I've described above and do some more testing (with log messages to show zoom levels) and you will be able to narrow down the problem.

Comment: If you want, post an example code suffering from the problem and I'll check it. Regards

Comment: updated with some code. Also, if the device has internet the problem only remains until the map can load the first tiles. Some calculation with the tiles seem to fix the problem. I just dont know how I could cause this issue so that i mess up googles internal variables so that only active internet can fix them

Comment: This code is fine. The problem is on you `draw()` method, where for some reason you are drawing when zoom animation starts (this is when you press the zoom button), but you don't update the draw after zoom animation ends. You can confirm that by adding a new button that just do `mapView.invalidate()`. Pressing that button you will see that all draws will be drwan correctly. Post your `draw()` method.

Comment: no no no, dont worry, all is fine with the drawing, while 2-finger-zooming all my positions are draw nicely and are accurate, will update above post with some additional infos that i just found out

Comment: The problem of map not center properly when map tiles are not available is real, and also my app suffres from it. But that's a different problem from the one you describe with you application. I've already gave you a lot of hints about the problem with your app. Now it's up to you to decide what to do.